# How to parse xml-string(not a file) without namespace in Python 3.7.3?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I'm conveting string to xml. How to parse a XML without namespace?
Maybe you can advise other libs for working with XML-string?

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
country_data_as_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:aa="http://vio.pfr.ru/Statements/ApplyApplication/1.0"><soap:Header><wsa:MessageID>12fd0e5b78cf44c2a61a1c6fc238cc51</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>http://vio.pfr.ru/person/Application/MSKApplicationPortType/ApplyApplicationRequest</wsa:Action><GlobalProcessID>66826749770843f4bfc5f359a86165af</GlobalProcessID></soap:Header></soap:Envelope>' 
doc = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)  

      
for elem in doc:                    
    for i in elem:                  
        print(i)                    
        if i.tag == 'MessageID':    
            print(i)
```

Comment: When you say "parse a XML without namespace", do you mean that you want to ignore the namespaces?

Comment: @mzjn, yes you got it right. This should work like function iterparse

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. What is the expected result? What do you mean by "I'm conveting string to xml"? You already have XML (as a string).

Comment: You may want to have a look at [lxml](https://lxml.de/)

Comment: @mzjn, func fromstring() convert from string to XML

Comment: No, `fromstring()` parses XML from a string and returns an `Element` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will allow you to read the entire **xml** without using namespace schema:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
country_data_as_string = r"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                                <soap:Envelope 
                                xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                                xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
                                xmlns:aa="http://vio.pfr.ru/Statements/ApplyApplication/1.0">
                                    <soap:Header>
                                        <wsa:MessageID>12fd0e5b78cf44c2a61a1c6fc238cc51</wsa:MessageID>
                                        <wsa:Action>http://vio.pfr.ru/person/Application/MSKApplicationPortType/ApplyApplicationRequest</wsa:Action>
                                        <GlobalProcessID>66826749770843f4bfc5f359a86165af</GlobalProcessID>
                                    </soap:Header>
                                </soap:Envelope>
                        """
doc = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)  
for node in doc.iter():
    print(node.tag+': ', node.text)   # node.text has the data encompassed by the tags
```

The output for above:

```bash
{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope:  
                                    
{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Header:  
                                        
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing}MessageID:  12fd0e5b78cf44c2a61a1c6fc238cc51
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing}Action:  http://vio.pfr.ru/person/Application/MSKApplicationPortType/ApplyApplicationRequest
GlobalProcessID:  66826749770843f4bfc5f359a86165af
```

Comment: {namespace}Tag - I need the output to be like the tag GlobalProcessID
Now i will try your version of the code

Comment: You can split the tag using `split('}')[1]`